# Parameterized queries - can GeoJson object values be used?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, spatial-query

Consider the following:

Given the following document structure:

```
// Document using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Spatial.Point ...

public class test_doc
{

  public String id { get; set; }

  public Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Spatial.Point geopoint { get; set; }

  // More properties
  public String desc { get; set; }

}
```

Build a query without parameters ...

```
bounds_str = "{'type':'Polygon','coordinates':[[[-113.247049,53.657421],[-113.733431,53.657421],[-113.733431,53.393183],[-113.247049,53.393183],[-113.247049,53.657421]]]}";

sql_query_text = "SELECT * FROM testcontainer t WHERE ST_WITHIN( t.geopoint, " + bounds_str + ")";

query_def = new Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.QueryDefinition( sql_query_text );
```

When the above query is executed, the query works as expected:

```
Query Total time: 00:00:00.0067482
Total Request Units consumed: 6.73
Documents found: 2
```

Now build the SAME query using a parameter ...

```
sql_query_text = "SELECT * FROM testcontainer t WHERE ST_WITHIN( t.geopoint, @bounds )";

query_def = new Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.QueryDefinition( sql_query_text );

query_def.WithParameter( "@bounds", bounds_str );
```

When the above query is executed, we get a different (incorrect) result ...

```
Query Total time: 00:00:00.0054688
Total Request Units consumed: 3.1
Documents found: 0
```

Comment: Can you try by changing the Geospatial Configuration setting of container to 'geometry'?

Comment: @AnuragSharma-MSFT - unfortunately, changing to geometry is not an option as our data is geographic in nature and does not include a "boundingBox" (which is not required for geography, but is for geometry) -- according to the docs:  If you try to add an indexing policy with a boundingBox to a container with geography data type, it will fail.   Unclear as to why a specific data type should effect parameters in queries?